# force a created file or folder to have a specific stat struct

Tags: c, stat

I have a stat struct and I want to create a folder or a file and want to force it to have the same information as in the stat struct.
For instance:

```
create file: test.txt
The file's last modification date is today 16.01.2014
change file's stat so that it shows:
last modified on 01.01.2050
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to set the `mtime/atime` fields, you can use the [`utime()`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/utime) function. Use it after creating the file/directory.

The `mode` field is set with `chmod()`

The `uid/gid`, if you are root, are set with `chown()`.

The fields `size` and `nlinks` will have the correct value if you set the information they refer to (the data of the file and the directory structure that contains the file).

But the `ino`, `dev` and `ctime` fields are set internally by the system and cannot be changed. No reason you would like to set them, anyway.

Comment: I actually want to create a file with a specific stat struct! To be specific, I'm restoring a file that I have backep up before. The stat information must also be set accordingly.

Comment: On a second note, I just checked tar. Tar reserves ino and dev of the file. So it should be possible to do so!

Comment: @hhachem: Have you a reference/experiment for this? I find it hard to believe... what if you decompress the same tar file twice? The dev/ino pair must be unique!

Comment: I believe you are right. I just moved the .tar file somewhere else, extracted it and it gave me a different inode number. But when I was extracting it in the same directory as the original, it was replacing the original and returning the same inode number.

Comment: @hhachem: Well, when a file is deleted, its inode is marked as free and may be reused for later. So if you restore right after deleting, chances are that you get the same inode numbers (the `dev` is the device (volume) identifier so that is out of the question).

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can, but that's OK.

Much of the information in the `struct stat` is implementation details for the file system; the file "is the same" even if (for instance) it has a different inode.

You need to look at individual file-related library calls to make all the fields that *are actually relevant* match, though:

- `st_mode` can be set by [`chmod()`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/chmod)
- `st_uid` and `st_gid` can be set by [`chown()`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/chown)
- `st_atime` and `st_mtime` can be set by [`utime()`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/utime)

There's no single "set all the `stat` fields" function, since that wouldn't make sense.

Comment: interesting. I guess that should help me further. Thank you. I will have to accept rodrigo's answer though since he was faster to answer.